# Install Postman native app on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04

I am trying to install the Postman native app on a virtual machine with Ubuntu 17.04.

I followed the istructions present [here](https://blog.bluematador.com/posts/postman-how-to-install-on-ubuntu-1604/) and the program won't start up.

I installed `libgconf-2-4` and now the program starts, but all I get is a black window.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that the problem is generated by chromium inside VirtualBox.
Using `postman --disable-gpu` instead of simply `postman` solves the issue